# Console application fire a process then close itself

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, process

I'm writing a small updater for my app.
My flow would be like this:
app.exe -> call process(updater.exe) -> app.close()
Then, updater check if app is closed, then overwrites app.exe and other satellite assemblies.

So I need to do something like this: launch my C# exe app, fire a process for updater.exe, then close app, but without closing child process.

There's a way to build this kind of fire-and-forget process in .NET?

Thank you,
Nando

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) object.  You would just call Process.Start like so:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("updater.exe");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'm doing so, but seems that Process don't start...

I made a small helper class, called Updater:

```
Updater.CheckUpdates()
```

--> starts a Process who call "updater.exe -check", and that works (when process finished, control return to my main app). I evaluate return code of process, and the I set Updater.UpdatesAvalilable bool flag, if necessary.

```
Updater.ApplyUpdates()
```

--> starts a Process who call "updater.exe -update", that do the update work.

So, my code is like this:

```
    Updater.CheckUpdates();
    if (Updater.UpdatesAvailable)
    {
        Updater.ApplyUpdates();
        System.Environment.Exit(0);
    }
```

Process in Updater.ApplyUpdates() never run.
I know, is not elegant code, but I don't know how to achieve my goal. :-)

Thank you!
Nando

Answer (score 0):

Good morning guys.
I found a way to make it work, it seems.
In my helper class I wired events for getting stdIO and stdError, just to log something; removing those, I get my work done: process start and main exit! :-)

Just to make all know about it: my process declaration is now like this:

```
            Process process = new Process();
        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-update";
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "updater.exe";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        process.Start();
```

Thank you all!
Nando